# Unable to catch custom Exception in java

Tags: java, exception, jdbctemplate, spring-transactions

In my resource method i will get the below exception

```
@Override
    public Response registerByDebitCard(RegistrationRequest registrationRequest,BeanFilter beanFilter) {
        try {


            RegistrationResponse registrationResponse = registrationService.doRegister(registrationRequest, beanFilter);

            return Response.ok(registrationResponse).build();
        } catch (CannotCreateTransactionException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error Message is :: {}", e.getMessage());
            throw new RegistrationFailureException("MPYR0012", "Due to database technical problem signup failed");
        }
    }
```

If i catch above exception it works.
I try to catch this exception using my custom exception class i can't able to catch.Below is my custom Exception class.

```
public class TransactionManagerDBException extends CannotCreateTransactionException {

    /**
     * @param msg
     */
    public TransactionManagerDBException(String msg) {
        super(msg);

    }

    public TransactionManagerDBException(String msg, Throwable cause) {
        super(msg, cause);

    }

}
```

My Resource Method:

```
@Override
        public Response registerByDebitCard(RegistrationRequest registrationRequest,BeanFilter beanFilter) {
            try {


                RegistrationResponse registrationResponse = registrationService.doRegister(registrationRequest, beanFilter);

                return Response.ok(registrationResponse).build();
            } catch (TransactionManagerDBException e) {
                LOGGER.error("Error Message is :: {}", e.getMessage());
                throw new RegistrationFailureException("MPYR0012", "Due to database technical problem signup failed");
            }
        }
```

Now i am unable to catch this exception.Is their anything wrong in my exception handling.please explain what's wrong with my approach

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!!

Comment: Is `TransactionManagerDBExceptione` a typo ?

Comment: yes, it should be TransactionManagerDBException e

Comment: Where do you throw `TransactionManagerDBException` ?

Comment: I edited that in my post,thanks Berger

Comment: Don't log and throw: just pass `e` as the `cause` ctor parameter of your `RegistrationFailureException`.

Comment: @Berger,I didn't throw TransctionManagerDbException.I try to catch the spring CannotCreateTransactionException as my custom exception class TransactionManagerDBException

Comment: @AndyTurner,If i throw means i can't send the valid response i am using jersey.I have a mapper class for registrationfailureecxception it will send the response

Comment: Can you provide the code of the `doRegister` method ? This method must throw a `TransactionManagerDBException` and not a `CannotCreateTransactionException` if you want your code to work. The reason is that `TransactionManagerDBException` IS-A `CannotCreateTransactionException`. But the reverse is not true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `TransactionManagerDBException` IS-A `CannotCreateTransactionException`. But the reverse is not true. If your `registrationService` does throw a `CannotCreateTransactionException`, it is NOT a `TransactionManagerDBException`.

If you cannot change the `doRegister` method to throw a `TransactionManagerDBException`, you can only use a catch block using `CannotCreateTransactionException`.

Comment: ,thanks for the answer,But It's not even entering the doRegister method.CannotCreateTransactionException this exception occurs because of the database not connected problem

Comment: The call to `doRegister` is the first line of code, it's the first place of your try/catch block that can raise an Exception. Do you even enter the `registerByDebitCard` method ? If not, your problem is withing Spring context startup, and your try/catch block cannot  do anything about it...

Comment: Then I doubt you catch on `CannotCreateTransactionException` can work. If you even do not enter `registerByDebitCard`, there is no chance your catch can do anything.